# Ruby/ RoR - String Hash to Integer Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an Hash  @answers = params[:Answers].to_hash;

`<%= debug @answers %>` outs

```
--- 
"1": "2"
"7": "3"
"6": "4"
"4": "0"
```

Need to make the @answers to one like below

`@ans = {1 => 2, 7 => 3, 6 => 4, 4 => 0}`
`<%= debug @answers %>` outs

```
--- 
1: 2
7: 3
6: 4
4: 0
```

Comment: Why do you want that ? It's a debug so it's like you do `p` no `puts`

Comment: P: `debug`, in a Rails view, formats its argument into yaml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Black magic wizard reporting in:

```
answers = {"1" => "2", "3" => "4"}
Hash[*answers.to_a.flatten.map(&:to_i)] # => {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

Comment: double tested on ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2 . Make sure that "*" is present and answers is not empty

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code

```
@ans = {"1" => "2", "7" => "3", "6" => "4", "4" => "0"}
@foo_hash ={} #new_hash
@ans.each_pair{|k,v| @foo_hash.store(k.to_i,v.to_i)}
```

The @foo_hash will be `{1 => 2, 7 => 3, 6 => 4, 4 => 0}`

Then you can <%= debug @foo_hash %> to get the output in your YAML format